# How to delete / remove an app from Amazon Mobile Analytics?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-mobile-analytics

I have an app in Amazon Mobile Analytics, but I want to remove it from my managed apps, I've read the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobileanalytics/latest/ug/managing-apps.htmldocumentation) and there is no option to do it.

Can you please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no option in dashboard to delete the app. Only way to delete it is open a ticket with AWS support and ask them to delete it or email amazon-mobile-analytics@amazon.com and send them you app name and they will delete it for you.

Answer (score 2):

A "Delete App" button is now available:

AWS Management Console > Amazon Mobile Analytics > App Name: Manage Apps > Select {YOUR APP} in drop down list > [X] Select {YOUR APP} with check box > Click "Delete App" button